# Jquery datepicker date-range in same input & localisation with asp.net localisation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, localization, datepicker, date-range

I am using jquery datepicker, I want it for daterange in one textbox not seperate inputs.

```
$(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

This is the date-range in different inputs, **how can I merge it in one input?**

And I am building the site in 3 language with asp.net localisation, it changes with cultureinfo like "en" or "en-GB", **how can I change language of datepicker with asp.net culture?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datepicker doesn't have this functionality anymore, but there are loads of plugins and extensions that does.

http://dubrox.blogspot.se/2010/09/multiple-dates-picker-for-jquery-ui.html

http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html#range

http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker/

A quick Google search will reveal even more.

Comment: Do they have localisation?

Comment: Datepicker has localization (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization), and since a few of these are extensions to Datepicker, they depend on it's localization settings. For example, from MultiDatePickr: _"NOTE: the string format you should pass to multiDatePicker depends on the localization of datepicker."_

Comment: Thanks, 

I use keith-wood's datepick and localise files. I called it like that  `<script src="js/jquery.datepick-<%=Session["CultureInfo"] %>.js"></script>`